# SharePoint 2010: Use SP Usercontrols in custom application pages

Tags: development

I would like to use SharePoint User Controls in my custom application pages.
In VS2010 I've created a new project and added an application page.

I've added the follow Tagprefixes in my customapp.aspx page:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="wssawc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormSection" src="/_controltemplates/InputFormSection.ascx" %>
```

When I try to add an InputFormSection in the content section,
I get the warning and the page throws an error when loading:

Element 'InputFormSection' is not a known element. 
This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, 
or the web.config file is missing.

Did I miss to add something?
Putting a ~ in scr="~/_controltemplates...  did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need the ~/.

Here is a page i have built that you can reference:

http://spc3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/56394#1012106

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="InputFormSection" src="~/_controltemplates/InputFormSection.ascx" %>
```

Comment: Strange.. copy/pasted your code in VS2010 and the warning is still there.

Comment: Does the file exist on disk? C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES. Do you have similar imports as the one in the example project?

Comment: Files are all there, imports the same...
I ran another test and my code compiles and the page is displayed correctly... Only not to happy with the warnings which are still there.. A VS2010 bug?

Comment: oh i understand now, its just a visual studio warning. ignore those. you are developing the developing the web part as a control library (dll), so visual studio doesnt know how to bind a "web" path "~/_controltemplates"